# Macro runs - but not very well, and excel usually crashes (along with my whole PC)

Tags: vba, excel

obviously I'm really new to VBA- this my first Macro (and I had a blast making it), but it runs really poorly and crashes every time. Do you have any tips on how I can make it run more efficiently?

PS - I need to do the special paste/ find replace (£) because of a stange bug where blank cells (that had formulas) get pasted as non-blanks in the operation

```
Sub DTC_Generator()

Application.EnableEvents = False 'Prevents screen from moving through cells/events'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Prevents screen from tabbing'
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'prevents gray residue after copy/paste'
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False


'LOOP RANGE

Dim A As Integer
Lstrow = Sheet4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For A = 2 To Lstrow

    Sheet4.Activate
    Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select

    Lstrow = ActiveCell.Row

    Cells(A, 1).Copy

    Range("L1").Activate
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'BEGIN MACRO


    'PASTE PRE-GENERATOR ATTRIBUTES

    Sheet4.Activate

    Range("AA2:AL36").Delete

    Range("M2:X36").Copy
    Range("AA2:AL36").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("AA2:AL36").Copy

    Sheet7.Activate
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("A2:AL36").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="£", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("A2:AL36").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="£", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
    'DElETE OLD DATA


    'SELECT ATTRIBUTE DATA

    Sheet7.Activate

    Range("M2").Select

    'Loops through unique values until "no"

    Do Until ActiveCell = "No"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    'bumps it back 1 row and over 19 columns'

    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 19).Select
    ActiveCell.Name = "Bottom_Left"
    Range("BH2:Bottom_Left").Copy

    'PASTE INTO ATTRIBUTE INPUT FILE'

    Sheet2.Activate

    Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Lastrow = ActiveCell.Row
    Cells(Lastrow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next A

MsgBox ("success?")


End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure but I am guessing that the following could be a quick fix to your "crashing" problem.

Change:

```
Do Until ActiveCell = "No"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

to

```
Do Until ActiveCell.Value2 = "No" or ActiveCell.Value2 = vbNullString
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Actually I have to thank you for this post as this is a prime-case why one should always try to avoid `Do ... Loop` (if at all possible). These kind of loops go on forever and have a tendency to crash Excel whenever the "exit point" in the `until` clause is poorly selected. In this case you are saying that it should keep on going until the value of the `ActiveCell` is `No`. Yet, you are forgetting that the next available cell might not contain `No` but nothing instead. So, if this loop goes beyond your data grid (`UsedRange`) then it will keep on looking for `No` even in row 1,048,576 and beyond. This can easily crash your Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're asking it to do the same thing over and over again. When you write 'for a = 2 to lastrow' that means it's going to everything between that and 'next a', in this instance, 36 times. Did you mean to do that? One of the things it does 36 times is an infinite loop: 'do until active cell' just selects a cell, it looks like everything you want it to do is below 'loop' which means it will not do it to each active cell, plus, if it does not find 'active cell = no' it will never end (infinite loop) and crash you.

I took a guess as to what you're trying to accomplish but got lost after the loop. I've written some code to get you started and comments to help you out. Let me know what you're trying to do in the loop and I'll try to help.

```
Sub DTC_Generator()

Application.EnableEvents = False 'Prevents screen from moving through cells/events'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Prevents screen from tabbing'
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'prevents gray residue after copy/paste'
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Sheet4.Name = "DTC_Generator" 'by naming the sheet you can work 'with' it,
'thereby making the code specific to this workbook so if you have other workbooks open it will not get confused
'about which workbook it's processing

'avoid selecting and activating if at all possible, saves time/cpu resources

Dim A As Long 'integer is limited in its length, just go ahead and always use Long for numbers
Dim Lastrow1 As Long
Dim Lastrow2 As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim x As Variant

With ThisWorkbook

    With .Sheets("DTC_Generator")

    'seems like the data you want to use is in columns M:X so goon base last row on those
    Lastrow1 = .Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Lastrow2 = .Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    If Lastrow2 > Lastrow1 Then Lastrow = Lastrow2 Else Lastrow = Lastrow1


    .Cells.ClearFormats 'remove if you need to keep formats
    .Cells.Copy 'get more specific if you need to keep formulas
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Columns("A").Value = .Columns("A").Value 'this does the whole column at once, no need to loop through each cell
    .Range("L1").Value = .Range("A2").Value 'you were doing this for each cell in column A, doesn't seem right so I moved it here but you can move it if you need to
    'you were also recalculating your lastrow for every cell in A

    .Range("M2:X" & Lastrow).Copy
    .Range("AA2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'you don't need to move it to a separate sheet to clean it up
    'you may not need to do this at all, uncomment if you do
    '.Columns("AA:AAL").Replace What:="", Replacement:="£", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    '.Columns("AA:AAL").Replace What:="£", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        'this is better than a loop cuz it will def just do the range so an infinite loop won't happen and crash you
        'i think your "Do Until ActiveCell = "No"" was meant to loop through M2:X36, if so, do this
        For Each x In Range(.Range("M2"), .Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        '***************************************************
        'YOU LOST ME AFTER THIS - WHAT ARE YOU TRYING TO DO?
        '***************************************************

        Next x

    End With

End With

'be sure to turn stuff back on
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

MsgBox "success?"

End Sub
```